# how to redirect new page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router-dom

I am stuck with a problem. When I am trying to click on Signup button which is in inside the Signin dropdown, it's not open new page, it is came below the footer. I want to open new page when I click on signup button.
Can anyone tell me how can I do it

> App.js file

This is the app.js file where I create my route

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Banner from './components/Banner';
import Cards from './components/Cards';
import Chat from './components/Chat';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Banner />
        <Cards />
        <Chat />
        <Footer />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/signup'  component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

> Navbar.js

This is the navbar.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/content/dam/scom/images/logos/re1mu3b.png" alt="coco-cola" className="coco mr-3" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="navbar-brand ml-3" href=""><b>Skype</b></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skype to Phone</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skype Number</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Products
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Meet Now</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Skype Manager</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Skype with Alexa</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Skype for content Creator</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Skype For Business</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Get Help
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Skype Support</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Community</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Skype</a>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hosting a meeting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Sign In
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"  style={{textDecoration:'none'}}><i class="fas fa-user"></i> My Account</a>
                                <Link to='/signup' class="dropdown-item" href="#" style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>Sign Up</Link>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

> Signup.js
> this is the page where i want to redirect.

```
import React from 'react'

const Signup = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup;
```

Comment: You render your routes below the footer, and ***always*** render `<Navbar />, <Banner />, <Cards />, <Chat />, <Footer />`, so these components will always render above any routes. Can you clarify what you mean by "open new page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing react-router-dom within App.js. Any components that you add to App.js outside of a switch will display no matter what. The switch is just used to change what component is being rendered within the  tag. So in your App.js code, you are guaranteeing that your page will always have Navbar, Banner, Cards, Chat, and Footer rendered above Signup. react-router-dom is better suited for creating a general page layout in App.js, then rendering different components within it.

For this, you'll want to create two files:

- Homepage.js
- Signup.js

First, modify App.js and remove any components that will not be universal to every page on your site. Maybe you'll only want to keep the header:

> App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <!-- You'll insert your switches here -->
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}
```

You'll use your Homepage.js file to add in components unique to the homepage:

```
const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Homepage">
      <Banner />
      <Cards />
      <Chat />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can implement your Signup page however you want. Then modify your new App.js to include the switches:

> App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/homepage'  component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path='/signup'  component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}
```

This design will guarantee that every page has a header and footer, as those are the two components outside of switches in App.js.